# Help with Stair Lighting using HC-SR04 sensor and WS2812 LED Strip

Tags: programming, hc-sr04

Excuse my naivete in this as I am very new to Arduino and the programming of. I am trying to put together a project for stair lighting triggered by a ultrasonic sensor at the bottom of the stairs and turned off by an ultrasonic sensor at the top of the stairs and vise versa. I am using an WS2812 LED strip and have the lights travel up the stairs when going up and down when going down. I'm sure this is a project many of you have seen. I have searched the net and youtube and have found many examples of this project, none that I can find using the HC-SR04 sensor. I have managed to cobble together a code which works fine in both direction but it is intermittent in working. I'm sure it is something to do with timings as sometimes it will work fine first time but then others the sensor needs to be blocked for a couple of seconds.
I would also like to add an LDR to the project so it is only active at night. If any of you can point me in the right direction I would be really grateful. I have attached the code so you can see where I am at.
This is just a test code and the final project will have around 200 LEDS.
Thanks

```
#include <FastLED.h>
#define trigPin_up 2
#define echoPin_up 3
#define trigPin_down 4
#define echoPin_down 5
#define LED_PIN     7
#define NUM_LEDS    13
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];



void setup() {

    //Set Serial
  Serial.begin(9600);





  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, LED_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);

  pinMode(trigPin_up, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin_up, INPUT);
  pinMode(trigPin_down, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin_down, INPUT); 


}
 void loop(){
 if (trigPin_up, HIGH && trigPin_down, LOW);
 {
   short duration, distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin_up, LOW); 
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin_up, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin_up, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin_up, HIGH);
  distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;


  if (distance <= 50) {
  leds[0] = CRGB(255, 225, 255);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);  
  leds[1] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[2] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[3] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[4] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[5] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[6] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[7] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[8] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[9] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[10] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[11] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[12] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[13] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  }

{    short duration, distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin_down, LOW); 
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin_down, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin_down, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin_down, HIGH);
  distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;


  if (distance <= 50) {
  leds[0] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);  
  leds[1] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[2] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[3] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[4] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[5] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[6] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[7] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[8] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[9] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[10] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[11] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[12] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[13] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  }


else
if (trigPin_up, LOW && trigPin_down, HIGH);
  {



     short duration, distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin_down, LOW); 
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin_down, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin_down, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin_down, HIGH);
  distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;

  if (distance <= 50) {
  leds[13] = CRGB(255, 225, 255);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);  
  leds[12] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[11] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[10] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[9] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[8] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[7] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[6] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[5] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[4] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[3] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[2] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[1] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[0] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  }
{
  short duration, distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin_up, LOW); 
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin_up, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin_up, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin_up, HIGH);
  distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;

    if (distance <= 50) {
  leds[13] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);  
  leds[12] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[11] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[10] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[9] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[8] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  leds[7] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[6] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[5] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[4] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[3] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[2] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[1] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
   delay(100);
   leds[0] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  }
}

  }  
} 
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things with your code which you might need to look into.
Note: I'm doing this ontop of my head, so please correct me if I say something incorrect. ]

**First**, to check if values are equal, with an if-statement you'd have to use:

```cpp
//if (trigPin_up, HIGH && trigPin_down, LOW); not like this.
if (trigPin_up== HIGH && trigPin_down== LOW) {.....} //But like this
```

Do not use the ';' because that would be then end of the statement.

**Second**, there seems to be a random '{' without any statement beforehand, at line 88.

**Extra tip**
[You can use for loops!](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/control-structure/for/) 
So:

```cpp
leds[0] = CRGB(255, 225, 255);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  ....
  leds[13] = CRGB(255, 255, 255);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
```

becomes:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i <14; i++){
    leds[i] = CRGB(255, 225, 255);
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
  }
```

As a good exercise, could you try to clean up your code, edit it in the OP, and try if it works then?

Comment: The for loop at the end should only go up to 12 instead of 13, since there are only 13 elements in the array

Comment: I don't think so. At the top there are 13 elements defined, but there should be 14, since he wants to do 0 until 13, which are 14 different numbers.

Comment: But then the array needs to be define with 14 elements. `NUM_LEDS` is currently 13. If you are assuming, that the OP has 14 LEDs, you should include that assumption and also say, that the definition would have to be changed for that. People tend to copy&paste from the internet a lot, so it would be better to explain this, instead of just quietly assuming it.

Answer (score 0):

Calvin Bootsman is right with the errors, that he described, but there are more problems in your code.

1. Look at these two lines, that I got from your sketch. I already corrected, what Calvin had to say about the if statement.

   ```
   #define trigPin_up 2
   if (trigPin_up == HIGH && trigPin_down == LOW){
   ```

   You define `trigPin_up` as the number two. A define is read by the preprocessor. It will replace all occurances of `trigPin_up` with the number 2. `HIGH` and `LOW` are also defines (defined in the Arduino core) with the values 1 and 0. They also get replaced. After that the code goes to the actual compiler. So the compiler sees this if statement:

   ```
   if( 2 == 1 && 4 == 0)
   ```

   2 isn't equal 1 and 4 isn't equal 0, so the result is always false. That corrupts your complete logic. I'm sure you want to read the state of the pin. `trigPin_up` and siblings are only the pin numbers. For getting the real electrical state of the pin you need to actually read it via `digitalRead()`:

   ```
   if(digitalRead(trigPin_up) == HIGH && digitalRead(trigPin_down) == LOW){
   ```

   You can simplify this even more, when you know, that zero is treated as `false` and every other value as `true`:

   ```
   if(digitalRead(trigPin_up) && !digitalRead(trigPin_down)){
   ```

   The `!` before the second `digitalRead()` does a negation, so that the part after the `&&` will become true, if `digitalRead(trigPin_down)` evaluates to false.
2. Now look at these lines:

   ```
   #define NUM_LEDS    13
   CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];
   leds[13] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
   ```

   You create an array named `leds` with `NUM_LEDS` (13) elements. The first index is 0 (as we start to count from zero in most programming languages). But that means, that the last index in the array is 12, not 13. When doing `leds[13]=...` you actually write to a memory address outside of your array. It could be everything, what is saved there. And you overwrite it. This often is a hard to diagnose problem, since it can have very weird consequences. Calvin Bootsman also did this wrong in his answer. For the for loop you only should count to 12, meaning using `i < 13` or `i < NUM_LEDS` in the for loop.
3. Then I guess you don't really understand how the logic of interfacing the HC-SR04 works. The trigger pins, that you define, are outputs. Their state will only change, if you yourself change it via `digitalWrite()`. But that cannot happen, as you enclosed the statements doing it into the if statement. It does not make sense to read these pins either. Instead you should write if statements with the calculated distance. You could go with the following flow in you `loop()` function: Trigger first HC-SR04, read the echo back, trigger second HC-SR04, read the echo back, if statement to compare the calculated distances to a trigger value, in there if statements to decide, which one was triggered, execute the corresponding code in it.

---

Honestly I'm suprised, that your code even compiled. You should look into some basic C/C++ tutorials, so that you get the programming syntax right. Also you should carefully think about the logic of your program. Often it is better to first write down short notes, what the logic of the program should be, without really writing the code. That helps with focussing on the logic instead of the syntax. That can be done afterwards.

Comment: chrisl thanks for the feedback I will have a look into some basic C/C++ tutorials.